# How to know which user is talking to the bot

Tags: discord.py

I'm new to discord.py, and trying to make the bot respond to hi. How do the bot know who is talking to it?

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents().all())
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi" +  bot.user.name)
```

expected:
Bob: !hi
Bot: hi Bob
Alice: !hi
Bot hi Alice

now:
Bob: !hi
Bot: hi Bot
Alice: !hi
Bot hi Bot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bot.user.name` doesn't return the command user's name and has no relation to the command because of `bot`. Instead, it returns your `ClientUser.name` aka your bot name `Bot`.

`ctx` has the attribute `author` which gets the command user. This together with `name` attribute and you'll get the command user's name.

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents().all())
@bot.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi " +  ctx.author.name)
```

Instead of using string concatenation, you can also use f-strings

```
await ctx.send(f"hi {ctx.author.name}")
```

This way, you don't need to use the `+` or `str()` in the case of integers